# Joint Probability Density :How does one find the upper and lower bound values in Integration?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, statistics

If the joint probability density of X and Y is given by

$$f(x,y)= \begin{cases}
24xy  && \text{ for } 0 <x<1,0<y<1,x+y<1\\ 
 0 && \text{elsewhere}\\
\end{cases}$$

$\text{Find } P(X+Y < \frac{1}{2}).$

So for this question one must first draw a graph to show the values

[image]

There after one must solve through integration. The problem that I have is determining the lowerbound and upperbound for this problem.

$$\int \int 24xy\text{ dxdy}$$

Also I might have asked this before but for more clarification **"elsewhere"** basically means the complement?

Comment: Your boundaries are $x= 0, y = 0, y = \frac12 - x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you have two options for $X + Y<0.5$, $0<X<1$, $0<Y<1$. Note that Clearly neither $X$ nor $Y$ can be more than 0.5 because both $X$ and $Y$ are positive and their sum is less than 0.5.

1) Fix $X=x \in [0,0.5]$, then you have $Y+x<0.5$ which means that $Y<-x +0.5$. You also know that $Y>0$. So, $0<Y<-x +0.5$
$$\int_{x=0}^{0.5} \int_{y=0}^{-x+0.5} 24xy\text{ dxdy}$$

2) Fix $Y=y \in [0,0.5]$, then you have $y+X<0.5$ which means that $X<-y +0.5$. You also know that $X>0$. So, $0<X<-y +0.5$ 
$$\int_{y=0}^{0.5} \int_{x=0}^{-y+0.5} 24xy\text{ dxdy}$$.

Comment: I understand that the lower bound is zero yet why is the upperbound $\int^{\frac{1}{2}}$  and $ + \int^{-y+ \frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: why is there a $-y$

Comment: @LittleJon I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have a nice picture of your region.

Do you want to integrate by $x$ first or $y$ first.  In this case, it doesn't matter at all, the region and the function are symmetric.
Lets say we want to integrate with respect to $y$ first and $x$ second.  That seems more traditional.

Draw a line through your region parallel to the $y$ axis (if we were going to integrate with respect to $x$ first we would draw it parallel to the $x$ axis).

What are the endpoints of that line?

One endpoint is $y = 0.$

The other one... it is on the line $x+y = \frac 12$
After we we integrate with respect to $y,$ and apply our limits, we want the $y$'s to disappear.  How do we express the line with $y$ as a function of $x$?
$y = \frac 12 - x$
That is our upper limit!

Now for the $x$ limits.  That is a little easier.  What are the extreme values of $x$? $0, \frac 12$